# Creating distribution area to export addresses to Excel file

Tags: qgis

I need to create a couple of polygons, see the picture below.

Could I export the addresses in a polygon to an excel file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Execute [this query](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1InF) on Overpass Turbo, export the result to a GeoJSON file.

The polygon layer contain buildings with addresses:
[image]

2. Extract by location:
   [image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One more question: I created some polygones in one layer and named them with label '001', '002' .... Is it possible, to show just the results, which are in polygone with label 002 ?

Comment: You can [join](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributesbylocation) the polygon attributes to the buildings and then, for example [extract](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression) the polygons with label 002